# ''Had you better ........ than/or.........'' in positive questions?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, british-english

I had watched a tutorial about the use of ***''Had better''*** in positive questions.

İt was mentioned that ''Had better '' is used in positive questions to ask which option is better?

EG;

a)***Had you better*** stay here ***than*** leave? (asking staying or leaving better?)

An American native speaker said that this sentence (Had you

better......***than***..............)  is odd to him.

I wonder ,is this structure ok for native ***B.E*** speakers?

or the other option

b)***Had*** they ***better*** talk ***or*** be quiet?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more common in contemporary American English to ask

> Shouldn't we stay?

or

> Hadn't we better stay?

than

> Had we better stay?

But all three forms are used.  The last is relatively rare however.

Answer (score 1):

"Had better" is a modal phrase used to express recommendation and is a synonym of "should". However it is rare and awkward to use "had better" in the question form, use "should" instead. Example: "Should we go now? Yes, we'd better go before the traffic gets bad."